# How to pass another models fields to the next page

Tags: apex, visualforce

At the moment I have a custom VF page with fields that look this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!contact.name}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!contact.email}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!message.Body__c}" />
```

When submitted, the contact information will come through to the controller function I wrote inside a ContactExtension Controller that was made but the message object will be null.

```
public class ContactExtension {
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
    public List<string> VideoIds {get; set;}
    public Message__c message {get; set;}

    // Example function
    public PageReference send () {
        System.debug(contact);
        System.debug(message);
    }
}
// Result
DEBUG|Contact:{Email=dean@example.com, Id=00328000003QkVmAAK, Name=Dean D, FirstName=Dean, LastName=D}
DEBUG|null
```

Is there something else I need to define to allow the Message model to be passed through the form into the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the `contact` reference is working because your standard controller is for `Contact` and it is taking care of querying/newing the `Contact` object.

But for your `message` reference, you will need to create a new object (and also insert it later if you want to save it). One way to do that is to add this:

```
message = new Message__c();
```

to a constructor that you add to `ContactExtension`.